# :not selector won't exclude targeted elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm playing around with the :not selector, and would like to produce an image icon for every single area in my HTML file *except* for the navigation section. Each time I try the CSS below, it still produces the .PDF image logo in the nav section as well as everywhere else.

```css
body *:not(nav) [href*="pdf"]:after {
    content: url("pdf.png");
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav style="top: 400px; position: relative;">
    <ul class="nav-ul">
        <li class="nav-li-2 nav-mobile-li"><a class="nav-li-a" href="">Hello</a></li>
        <li class="nav-li-2 nav-mobile-li"><a class="nav-li-a" href="">Hello2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-li-2 nav-mobile-li"><a class="nav-li-a" href="pdf.png">Another PDF</a></li>
        <a href="pdf.png">PDF</a>
        <a href="intmark.png">INTMARK</a>
        <a href="browser.png">BROWSER</a>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p>
    <a href="pdf.png">PDF</a> This is just a paragraph in a page with fixed footer</p>
<p>This is just a paragraph in a page with fixed footer</p>
```

Comment: try removing the space: ```body *:not(nav)[href*="pdf"]:after{...```

Comment: I think the problem is the fact it is any parent that is not nav.... It would need to be something like `body *:not(nav)>* [href*="pdf"]:after`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to select elements with `href` attributes that are descendants of any element except `nav`.

The problem with your selector is that the `href` attributes inside the `nav` element are *also* descendants of `ul` and `li` elements, so `:not()` doesn't match.

Remove the `ul` and `li` tags from your code, and your selector works as intended.

Here's a possible solution:

```css
body > *:not(nav) > * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-ul">
    <li class="nav-li-2"><a class="nav-li-a" href="">Hello</a></li>
    <li class="nav-li-2"><a class="nav-li-a" href="">Hello2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-li-2"><a class="nav-li-a" href="pdf.png">Another PDF</a></li>
    <a href="pdf.png">PDF</a>
    <a href="intmark.png">INTMARK</a>
    <a href="browser.png">BROWSER</a>
  </ul>
</nav>

<p>
  <a href="pdf.png">PDF</a> This is just a paragraph in a page with fixed footer
</p>
```

OR, more specifically to your question:

```css
body > *:not(nav) > [href*="pdf"]::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-ul">
    <li class="nav-li-2"><a class="nav-li-a" href="">Hello</a></li>
    <li class="nav-li-2"><a class="nav-li-a" href="">Hello2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-li-2"><a class="nav-li-a" href="pdf.png">Another PDF</a></li>
    <a href="pdf.png">PDF</a>
    <a href="intmark.png">INTMARK</a>
    <a href="browser.png">BROWSER</a>
  </ul>
</nav>

<p>
  <a href="pdf.png">PDF</a> This is just a paragraph in a page with fixed footer
</p>
```